# How can we publish and subscribe an event in playwright in angular?

Tags: playwright

I got something mentioned below in official website of playwright. But it is not very clear and also no where its mentioned how can we manually publish or trigger an event.
Also if someone can clarify what is the meaning of page.on here?

**In Playwright official website**
Adding/removing event listener#
Sometimes, events happen in random time and instead of waiting for them, they need to be handled. Playwright supports traditional language mechanisms for subscribing and unsubscribing from the events:

page.on('request', request => console.log(`Request sent: ${request.url()}`));
const listener = request => console.log(`Request finished: ${request.url()}`);
page.on('requestfinished', listener);
await page.goto('https://wikipedia.org');

page.off('requestfinished', listener);
await page.goto('https://www.openstreetmap.org/');